# How to insert a value in the index of a multi-index data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to introduce the current time in the index of a data frame that only has one row.

This is the data frame:

```
COIN    $ANRX                                                                              
                                                                                                                             $BASED ... ZRX ZT
        24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks Contributors    FB Likes    Market Cap Dominance    Mkt Cap Price   Reddit Subscribers  24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks ... Price   Reddit Subscribers  24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks Contributors    FB Likes    Market Cap Dominance    Mkt Cap Price   Reddit Subscribers
TIME                                                                                    
0       $483,788    0   0
```

And this is what I want:

```
COIN    $ANRX                                                                              
                                                                                                                             $BASED ... ZRX ZT
                        24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks Contributors    FB Likes    Market Cap Dominance    Mkt Cap Price   Reddit Subscribers  24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks ... Price   Reddit Subscribers  24h Volume  Commits in Last 4 Weeks Contributors    FB Likes    Market Cap Dominance    Mkt Cap Price   Reddit Subscribers
TIME                                                                                    
'11:51 14/03/2021'      $483,788    0   0
```

The time is taken using this code (in case you want to know)

```
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
current_time
```

Comment: can you please tell the output of  `df.index`

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1, name='TIME')

Comment: It is not a multi index!

Comment: Oh!! Sorry for my ignorant. Can you tell me what is this and I will change the question

Comment: just use `df=df.set_index('current_time')`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary `TIME` column, populate it with `datetime.now()`, set it as `DatetimeIndex` and drop the temporary column:

```
df['TIME'] = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['TIME']))
df = df.drop(columns=['TIME'])
```

Comment: I got this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Did you get that when running my code or when working on your df afterwards?